# What's the Derivative of Order $\frac{1}{3}$ of $f(x)=x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation, fractional-calculus

So, I'm very new to Fractional Calculus, and I don't know too much about series, but I'm very interested in Fractional Calculus, so I wanted to know if you could find the solution to this problem.

Using the general formula for derivatives:$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\epsilon^n}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{x}{\epsilon}\rfloor}\frac{f(x-j\epsilon)(-1)^j}{j!\Gamma(n+1-j)}$$
Where $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function. The upper limit to the summation (because it's a little hard to see) is $\lfloor{\frac{x}{\epsilon}\rfloor}$, which is the floor function.
I want to find:$$\frac{d^{\frac{1}{3}}}{dx^{\frac{1}{3}}}(x)$$

The place where I get stuck is interpreting the upper limit of the summation. Am I supposed to treat it as an infinite series since it has a variable?

The place I got this formula is: [Link w/ Formula](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath616/kmath616.htm)

Comment: The result is given in equation (5) of the link you have provided.

Comment: General, the fractional extension for your general derivative formula has an upper bound that grows to infinity as $\epsilon\to0$. [Grünwald–Letnikov derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnwald%E2%80%93Letnikov_derivative)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, one extends the formula

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} x^m = m (m-1) \cdots (m-n+1) x^{m-n} = \frac{m!}{(m-n)!}x^{m-n}$$

to

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} x^m = \frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m-n+1)} x^{m-n}$$

Thus,

$$\frac{d^{1/3}}{dx^{1/3}} x= \frac{\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(5/3)} x^{2/3} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(5/3)} x^{2/3}$$

Comment: Oh boy was I over complicating things, thanks!

Comment: Are you certain your solution matches up with the definition the OP gave?

Answer (score 0):

#### Introduction

There is no such thing as "the one [Fractional Derivative](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html)", as there is in [Fractional Calculus](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalCalculus.html) in general. The result varies depending on the definition of the differential operator and the type of derivation. A classic example of this was given by Leonhard Euler for the exponential function.

I'll use $\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}$ as a differential operator given by $\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}} = \frac{\operatorname{d}^{\alpha}}{\operatorname{d}x^{\alpha}}$. Note: I'll also use $\Gamma\left( \cdot \right)$ as the [Complete Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html).

---

#### Calculation

##### Calculation Via "Euler Method"

We can do this even mor generaly for $\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right]$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \ni \alpha$.

Leonhard Euler came up with a nice method for some [Fractional Derivatives](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html) (see Euler's Approach). He has sorted the derivatives of the function by order and is trying to find a pattern in it. He then tried to transfer this pattern from integer orders to fractional ones, which I always affectionately call the "Euler method":

$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D_{x}^{0}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{1}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a \cdot c \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - 1}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{2}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{2} \cdot c \cdot \left( c - 1 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - 2}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{3}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{3} \cdot c \cdot \left( c - 1 \right) \cdot \left( c - 2 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - 3}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{4}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{4} \cdot c \cdot \left( c - 1 \right) \cdot \left( c - 2 \right) \cdot \left( c - 3 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - 4}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{5}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{5} \cdot c \cdot \left( c - 1 \right) \cdot \left( c - 2 \right) \cdot \left( c - 3 \right) \cdot \left( c - 4 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - 5}\\
&\cdots\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{n}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{n} \cdot c \cdot \left( c - 1 \right) \cdot \left( c - 2 \right) \cdots \left( c - n + 1 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - n},\, &\text{for}\, n \in \mathbb{N}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{n}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{n} \cdot \frac{c!}{\left( c - n \right)!} \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - n},\, &\text{for}\, n \in \mathbb{N}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{\alpha} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left( c + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( c - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - \alpha},\, &\text{for}\, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\\
\end{align*}
$$

$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{\alpha} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left( c + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( c - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - \alpha},\, &\text{for}\, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\\
\end{align*}
$} \tag{1.1}$$

You can simplify this even further with the [Falling Factorial Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html) $x^{\left( \underline{y} \right)} = \left( x \right)_{y} \equiv \frac{\Gamma\left( x + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( x - y + 1 \right)}$:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{\alpha} \cdot c^{\left( \underline{\alpha} \right)} \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - \alpha},\, &\text{for}\, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\\
\end{align*}
$} \tag{1.2}$$

We can du the same for $c \in \mathbb{R}^{-1}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D_{x}^{0}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c} \right] &= \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{1}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= -a \cdot c \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c - 1}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{2}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{2} \cdot c \cdot \left( c + 1 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c - 2}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{3}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= -a^{3} \cdot c \cdot \left( c + 1 \right) \cdot \left( c + 2 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c - 3}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{4}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= a^{4} \cdot c \cdot \left( c + 1 \right) \cdot \left( c + 2 \right) \cdot \left( c - 3 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c - 4}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{5}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= -a^{5} \cdot c \cdot \left( c + 1 \right) \cdot \left( c + 2 \right) \cdot \left( c + 3 \right) \cdot \left( c + 4 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c - 5}\\
&\cdots\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{n}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c} \right] &= \left( -a \right)^{n} \cdot c \cdot \left( c + 1 \right) \cdot \left( c + 2 \right) \cdots \left( c + n - 1 \right) \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{c - n},\, &\text{for}\, n \in \mathbb{N}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{n}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c} \right] &= \left( -a \right)^{n} \cdot \frac{\left( c + n -1 \right)!}{\left( c - 1 \right)!} \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c - n},\, &\text{for}\, n \in \mathbb{N}\\
\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c} \right] &= \left( -a \right)^{\alpha} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left( c + \alpha \right)}{\Gamma\left( c  \right)} \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c - \alpha},\, &\text{for}\, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\\
\end{align*}
$$

$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c} \right] &= \left( -a \right)^{\alpha} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left( c + \alpha \right)}{\Gamma\left( c  \right)} \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c - \alpha},\, &\text{for}\, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\\
\end{align*}
$} \tag{2.1}$$

You can simplify this even further with the [Rising Factorial Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RisingFactorial.html) (sometimes called the Pochhammer Symbol) $x^{\left( \overline{y} \right)} \equiv \frac{\Gamma\left( x + y \right)}{\Gamma\left( x  \right)}$:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c} \right] &= \left( -a \right)^{\alpha} \cdot x^{\left( \overline{\alpha} \right)} \cdot \left( a \cdot x + b \right)^{-c - \alpha},\, &\text{for}\, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\\
\end{align*}
$} \tag{2.2}$$

This Formulas give you the solution:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\operatorname{d}x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\left( x \right) &= 1^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot 1^{\left( \underline{\frac{1}{3}} \right)} \cdot \left( 1 \cdot x + 0 \right)^{1 - \frac{1}{3}}\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\operatorname{d}x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\left( x \right) &= 1^{\left( \underline{\frac{1}{3}} \right)} \cdot x^{\frac{2}{3}}\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\operatorname{d}x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\left( x \right) &\approx 1.1077\dots \cdot x^{\frac{2}{3}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

aka

$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\operatorname{d}x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\left( x \right) &= 1^{\left( \underline{\frac{1}{3}} \right)} \cdot x^{\frac{2}{3}}\\
\end{align*}
$} \tag{*}$$

wich plot looks like:

[image: 1/Γ(5/3) x^(2/3) by Wolfram|Alpha]

You can write this in terms of roots too as Wolfram|Alpha shows [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UHZP.png).

I createt an **[interactive plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ryogdlgprk)** where you can animate the the change of the exponentent and the Order of the derivative.

##### Calculation Via Integral Formula

We might wanna use the formulas for simplifying mutible integrals into single integral . Some Differential Operators are defind with this fomula like the [Riemann-Liouville Differential Operator](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-LiouvilleOperator.html):
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{_{a}D^{-v}_{x}}\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] \equiv \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( v \right)} \cdot \int\limits_{a}^{x} f\left( u \right) \cdot \left( x - u \right)^{v - 1} \, \operatorname{d}u\\
\end{align*}
$$

Via using this we would get
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{_{0}D_{x}^{\frac{1}{3}}}\left[ x \right] &= \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( -\frac{1}{3} \right)} \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{x} u \cdot \left( x - u \right)^{-\frac{1}{3} - 1}\, \operatorname{d}u\\
\operatorname{_{0}D_{x}^{\frac{1}{3}}}\left[ x \right] &= \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( -\frac{1}{3} \right)} \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{x} u \cdot \left( x - u \right)^{-\frac{4}{3}}\, \operatorname{d}u\\
\operatorname{_{0}D_{x}^{\frac{1}{3}}}\left[ x \right] &= \frac{1}{\Gamma\left( -\frac{1}{3} \right)} \cdot \left[ -\frac{3 \cdot \left( a - 3 \cdot x \right)}{2 \cdot \left( -a + x \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right]_{0}^{x}\\
\end{align*}
$$

This does not converge. It diverges to $\hat{\infty}$ ([Complex Infinity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexInfinity.html)).